# Handle complex styles with js/ts instead of css-pre-processors

Tags: javascript, sass, vuejs2, mixins

I've worked with scss and stylus as I like their extra capabilities, especially mixins. Yet I've started to face ugly spots where even they cannot fully come up for the logic I need and I was forced to mix in some separate script-based styling ending up with different approaches in the same app.

Programming in Vue, I wonder why not just switch completely to js/ts controlled styling, writing your style helper functions fully flexible and then just assign "styles".

Example:

```
<template>
   <div v-for="(el, index) in elements" :key="el.id" :style="getStyle(el.value)">
   </div>
</template>

<script>
   getStyle(index) {    
      return colorScaleHelper(background, index)
   }


   // helper function; potentially with a variety of different possibilities to calculate and define the right colors for different use cases

   colorScaleHelper(prop: string, index: number, range?: number, reverse?: boolean) {
        // ...

        const colors = ['rgba(negative, 1)', 'rgba(negative, 0.75)', 'rgba(warning, 1)', 'rgba(positive, 0.75)', 'rgba(positive, 1)']

        return `${prop}: ${colors[index]}`
   }
</script>
```

Looking at this approach, it feels more flexible as we handle the styling through script. I'm not a React developer and still rather new to programming but I think I've heard a similar concept there as well. What is the reason I haven't seen this more often? Why the hassle to build complex css with e.g. scss? And in case this approach above is feasible, what are potential disadvantages or risks?

Comment: I've used this same method too, but only when I really need to use JavaScript for more complicated functions that sass can handle. So, I'd say it's a good workaround when you need it

Comment: @CascadiaJS What I dislike about it is that you'll have even more places to look for your styles and their handling. In this particular case I ended up having two redundant color tables, one in scss and one in js which of course is not great. But for now, I guess I will stick to this.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, but I found that it's possible to share variables between scss and JavaScript. So, I created a file of scss variables and shared them with my JS, so I still only had one source of truth. Here's the tutorial: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/sxbrscjuqu-share-scss-variables-with-javascript